# Getting Error #1064 Near End When Trying to Create a Trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER DELETETRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON WORKLOG
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO WORKLOGCOPY (Log_ID, Order_ID, Employee_ID, Client_ID, 
Work_Completed, Hours_Taken, Date_Logged)
    VALUES(OLD.Log_ID, OLD.Order_ID, OLD.Employee_ID, OLD.Client_ID, 
OLD.Work_Completed, OLD.Hours_Taken, OLD.Date_Logged)
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'END' at line 6
```

Have tried messing around with the syntax to match examples I have seen but with no luck.

Using MySQL on phpmyadmin if that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Add `;` at the end of `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `;` at the end of `INSERT INTO`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER DELETETRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON WORKLOG
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO WORKLOGCOPY (Log_ID, Order_ID, Employee_ID, Client_ID, 
Work_Completed, Hours_Taken, Date_Logged)
    VALUES(OLD.Log_ID, OLD.Order_ID, OLD.Employee_ID, OLD.Client_ID, 
OLD.Work_Completed, OLD.Hours_Taken, OLD.Date_Logged);
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Holy crap, I tried this before but it showed me a red cross and a squiggly line indicating that it's wrong. This time I tried to actually run it and it ran perfectly! THANK YOU!

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes